# Using MPI_Scatter with char* array

Tags: c++, mpi

I am new to MPI programming. So I am trying to use MPI_Scatter to distribute an array of char* that have static size into several smaller chunk of array of char*. But the result only correct for the ID 0 and the rest have garbage value. Do you know what is wrong with it?

```
#include "mpi.h"
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <cctype>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
const static int ARRAY_SIZE = 130000;
using Lines = char[ARRAY_SIZE][16];

// To remove punctuations
struct letter_only: std::ctype<char> 
{
    letter_only(): std::ctype<char>(get_table()) {}

    static std::ctype_base::mask const* get_table()
    {
        static std::vector<std::ctype_base::mask> 
            rc(std::ctype<char>::table_size,std::ctype_base::space);

        std::fill(&rc['A'], &rc['z'+1], std::ctype_base::alpha);
        return &rc[0];
    }
};


int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    int processId;
    int fillarraycount=0;
    int num_processes;

    // Setup MPI
    MPI_Init( &argc, &argv );
    MPI_Comm_rank( MPI_COMM_WORLD, &processId);
    MPI_Comm_size( MPI_COMM_WORLD, &num_processes);

    Lines lines;
    // Read the input file and put words into char array(lines)
    if (processId == 0) {
        std::ifstream file;
        file.imbue(std::locale(std::locale(), new letter_only()));
        file.open(argv[1]);
        std::string workString;
        int i = 0;
        while(file >> workString){
            memset(lines[i], '\0', 16);
            memcpy(lines[i++], workString.c_str(), workString.length());
            fillarraycount++;
        }
    }
    int n =fillarraycount/num_processes;
    char sublines[n][16];

    MPI_Scatter(lines,n*16,MPI_CHAR,sublines,n*16,MPI_CHAR,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    std::cout<< processId<<" ";
    for(int i=0;i<n;++i)
        std::cout<<sublines[i]<<" ";
    std::cout<<std::endl;

    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

I know i have to use MPI_gather too after that, but I am confused on why the sublines on ID 0 produced the correct chunk of the array but the other IDs produced garbage value.

I tried compiling and testing the program with:
module load openmpi
mpic++ -std=c++11 try.cpp -o try
mpirun -np 5 try try.txt

where in try.txt:
    hello this is the try text document
    again this is the try text document
    is is notis si is is is is ha ha

Comment: this probably won't help, I remember running into a similar problem and fixed it by using pointers and `malloc` instead of arrays.  (`char [x][y] -> char *sublines = malloc(sizeof(char)*x*y)`).  the only other things that stick out are make sure `num_processes` is defined at compile time (otherwise declaring the array like that is not valid, it's not possible to know how much memory to allocate), and final sanity check: you did the scatter, **did you gather your results back**? you have to [scatter and gather](http://mpitutorial.com/tutorials/mpi-scatter-gather-and-allgather/) ;)

Comment: Please provide an [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

On ranks other than 0, `n` is 0 because `fillarraycount` is never incremented. If `fillarraycount` is dynamic, you must broadcast ist first to all ranks.

Comment: thanks for the reply!  can you explain in a bit more, I really want to fully understand the problem..  thanks!